# does tor used on mobile networks disable tracking of location?

Tags: mobile

If i use a tor program like orbot, then all the data goes through tor, so the location should be hidden.
does this also apply to radio cell query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

What you are referring to, even if Tor is set up as a VPN, is separate from normal network. Your ISP or cell provider will still know,or other apps if you have other location services on your device,like GPS

However, website and apps, unless given location permission, won't be able to. Most of them tell from your IP, which Tor will hide

Comment: Exactly. Even more, you can change your phone time zone to your VPN (or TOR exit node) in order to be more transparent to the servers (which applications are connected to).